# google sheets sum on previous rows data + constant variable

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, sum, array-formulas, cumulative-sum

I'm currently facing a problem which I cannot solve, would appreciate help.

a link to the spreadsheet

[click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vRbKnV2FLlYZShxGhcMwQLrEGzdFiFeKOUNle6snMR6ahj09CWR8GrZBgCGDOJ8wgZT0PpCJtuhRH_c/pubhtml?gid=1435644043&single=true)

now, here is the problem.
I want H to be calculated by the sum of previous months(H)+ portfolio size(K8) * G of the current row. in array formula so I won't need to add the function each time I create a new row.

but if it exceeds 10,000 that it will be G(current row)*10,000.

for example:

row 4, `IF(portfolio size + SUM (H2:H3)>10000,G4*10000,G4* (portfolio size(K8) + SUM (H2:H3)))`

row 5, `IF(portfolio size + SUM (H2:H4)>10000,G4*10000,G4* (portfolio size(K8) + SUM (H2:H4)))`
 and so on.

would appreciate the help

Comment: share an editable copy of your sheet

Comment: @player0 https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1-0Yjl8XmiZDj65cz9EzDIZJknutf-8kXreL6w4C3KmU/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: @player0 it is in the Summary tab

Comment: is that in H column where you need it?

Comment: @player0 yes in the H column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A2:A="",,IF(K8+IF(A2:A="",,
 {0; MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*G2:G*K8), 
 SIGN(G2:G)^0)})>K8,G2:G*K8, (K8+IF(A2:A="",,
 {0; MMULT(TRANSPOSE((ROW(B2:B)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(B2:B)))*G2:G*K8), 
 SIGN(G2:G)^0)}))*G2:G)))
```

[image]